# How to host and manage databases for web development?

Tags: php, sql, web

So I've been learning the main technologies for web development and I really wanted to know what are the best options to store and manage my databases.
I have been using XAMPP to store all my files, HTML, PHP, JS and so on, but how do I manage my databases? 
Any suggestion on how to keep track of the data on them?

Comment: XAMPP comes with MYSQL and phpMyAdmin. You got everything you need already!

Answer (score 1):

Its best for you to work locally on xampp other than using other local servers. for startup its most easy for you to use. http://localhost/phpmyadmin is platform where you will be able to manage your database . xampp/htdocs/Yourfolder will be place where you can manage your project files . 
Choose your favorite editor .
hope you understand

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I did understand it! One more question, where would you create your SQL and subsequently db files?

Comment: Go to //localhost/phpmyadmin you will find a complete database window. on top menu you will find databases tab. click on it you will see a list of databases . same time there will be a text field and button for new database creations. if you want to import check top tabs and you will find options for it . if you want to check files go to xampp folder and mysql folder in it . you will be able to see files too

Answer (score 0):

Use XAMPP only for development!

Normaly you have a Webserver and a Database server (like MySQL or PostgreSQL).

On the webserver there is a directory called "www" or something like that. Within that dir all your files go in.

On the database Server you have your databases.
But you can't "keep track of the data". A database is a folder with some files that can only be read by the database.

If you want to import/export/backup the data, there are manager tools to write the data into an extra file / read data from an extra written file.

Comment: I may not have expressed myself correctly, I do believe I only use XAMPP for development, and store my files on the apache server, using and FTP. So where do you advise me to create the database?

Comment: If you mean just for development reasons then you can create a database with XAMPP also.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at phpMyAdmin - allows to manage MySQL databases visually through the web browser

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to create and manage databases on a server is via PHPMyAdmin.

First you will need to install MySQL on your server and then install phpmyadmin into a sub folder of your websites root directory.

If using linux both of these steps are very simple and there is numerous guides on the topic.

After that you can use PHPMyAdmin to import an existing SQL database or create new ones from scratch.